# Relational-Database Design

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

[image]

I want to know if my database design is good or not?

Comment: Not sure if I am unique in this regard, but when a schema goes beyond about 3 tables (or objects, or whatever depending on paradigm) and I see a visual diagram instead of the data definition code, I just shut down. Ironically,I find it too difficult to visualize internally. Can you paste the code?

Comment: Without any **context** as to what your database is intended for - no one can tell you whether it's "good" or not. Whether or not a database design is "good" depends on your **requirements** and what your system is intended to do

Comment: It's better than some, not as good as others.  What would you like to know, specifically?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what you're trying to accomplish. What is the problem that you're trying to solve? I think you would be better off to pick out one or two specific points where you are most unsure and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

The very intelligent way to check if your relational model is good or not is not make sure it obeys `Normalization` rules (NF1, NF2, NF3).